# Is there a way to get the executing app name from within an app flow?

Tags: mule

I am using the following to read property files:

```
<spring:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <spring:property name="locations">
    <spring:list>
     <spring:value>file:${MULE_HOME}/conf/general.properties</spring:value>
    </spring:list>
  </spring:property>
  <spring:property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
  <spring:property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
</spring:bean>
```

I would like to be able to read a property file that is distinct to a particular app with something like the following:

```
<spring:value>file:${MULE_HOME}/conf/**${currentappname}**.properties</spring:value>
```

Is there any way to get the name of the currently executing application from Mule so I can grab the property file for a specific application without having to code the full filename into the Mule flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mule there is Mule Expression language to get the current Application name.
Why don't you use mule expression like #[app.name]   to get the app name, example :-

```
<spring:value>file:${MULE_HOME}/conf/#[app.name].properties</spring:value>
```

Please find the reference here :-

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL